# how do offset top when using slideto with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, offset

I can get the page to slide to the div i want, but i want the div to be offset from the top by 25 px, anyone have any idea of to fix my code

```
$('#project_btn').bind('click', function() {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#project_page").offset().top
},1000);
});
```

Also does anyone know how i could get my menu bar to always stay at the top of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unsure of what you are wanting, but look at this example?: http://jsfiddle.net/lathan/cMTMm/